# MVC application calling resources multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, fiddler

When I use fiddler to diagnose my mvc web application I am noticing that there are multiple calls to resources that return 401 unauthorized errors but then proceed.

```
    Result Protocol URL                      Body  Caching Content-Type
1   401    HTTP     /administration/index    6,334 private text/html; charset=utf-8
2   401    HTTP     /administration/index    341           text/html; charset=us-ascii
3   200    HTTP     /administration/index    511   private text/html; charset=utf-8
... images and stylesheets also return the same sequence
    401    HTTP     /administration/logo.png 6,322         text/html; charset=utf-8
    401    HTTP     /administration/logo.png 341           text/html; charset=us-ascii
    200    HTTP     /administration/logo.png 3,124         image/png
```

This happens for both the page I am visiting and images.

The website is running under its own application pool with ApplicationPoolIdentity and there is windows authentication on the website.

It looks like the resources are being called multiple times for different charsets?

Can anyone advise as to what may be causing this to occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I use fiddler to diagnose my mvc web application I am noticing
>   that there are multiple calls to resources that return 401
>   unauthorized errors but then proceed.

That's perfectly normal if you are using [`Integrated Windows Authentication`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_In_IIS#Integrated_Windows_Authentication). Windows Authentication (a.k.a) NTLM is a challenge response authentication scheme where the client sends a request to a protected resource, and the server returns 401 and a challenge. Then the client uses this challenge to generate an Authorization header proving that the user is the one he is presenting to be without ever sending the password. The domain controller is used by both parties as intermediary.

If you look at the response headers you should see something along the lines of:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Access Denied
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
```

Then the client attempts to authenticate a second time:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: host
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IAoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB=
```

Now the server sends a challenge to the client:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Access Denied
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAADAAMADAAAAAFgoGgCY6qiih5j bAAAAAAAAAAAH4AfgA8AAAAUABPAFIAVAA4ADAAAgAMAFAATwBSAFQA OAAwAAEACgBKAEwASQBNAEEABAAkAHAAbwByAHQAOAAwAHMAbwBmA HQAdwBhAHIAZQAuAGMAbwBtAAMAMABqAGwAaQBtAGEALgBwAG8AcgB0 ADgAMABzAG8AZgB0AHcAYQByAGUALgBjAG8AbQAAAAAA
```

and finally the client responds to this challenge:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: host
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAGIAAAAYABgAegAAAAwADAB AAAAACgAKAEwAAAAMAAwAVgAAAAAAAACSAAAABYKAoFAATwBSAFQAO AAwAGoAbABpAG0AYQBFAFIATgBFAFMAVACZTd1Br98zFkTowoPysC5ysMaXqb qycwRldOKyZJbCIZLxCfcZe3ZHiYQmG97jr89=
```